# Automatically adding attachments to all outgoing mail messages

Tags: applescript

A two-part newbie question, guys... I've only just discovered AppleScript and I'm hoping to automagically attach a 'pdf' file to every outgoing (sent) "Mail.app" message.

(Q1) I've got it working successfully in tests running direct from Script Editor - with the file located in the Documents folder - and I'm using:

```
set pdfFile_Path to ((path to documents folder as text) & "paginatedPDF.pdf")
```

but the filepath bit confuses me... How would I change this line if I wanted to store my file inside a folder called "PDF's to send" on my **desktop**?

(Q2) How can I attach the script as a Mail.app rule (the rule options only seem to offer incoming mail message conditions, not outgoing ones)?

Any help/advice much appreciated. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried dragging and dropping the PDF straight into your Signature?

Comment: Hi karudzo. Thanks for the input. I've only been at it a coupla days now, so I'm not certain what you say. I can get the correct filepath if that's what you mean (it's "Mac HD1:Users:Administrator:Desktop:testFolder:") but what worries me is the "path to documents folder as text" bit. Clearly, I'm not using the 'documents' folder, and I'm wondering if there's something like a "path to desktop folder" or similar...

Comment: It's much easier than you're trying.  Try these steps:  1. Open Mac Mail, 2. Click on Mail ― Preferences, 3. Open Signatures and create one for your email address if necessary,  4. Drag the PDF straight into the signature.  5. Switch to another tab in the Preferences area to force it to save.  6. Create an email and, voila, your PDF is attached.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot buddy! I guess I was just anticipating a 'hard' solution and was over-thinking the problem. Appreciate your help :-)

Comment: No problem.  You should've seen me when I first got a Mac years ago; I was looking everywhere for an Attach button in Mail and, on a whim, dragged an image in and it worked!  It's typically more intuitive than we assume in Mac land!